# Cannot add new field when Project Config enabled

Tags: projectconfig

I'm working locally and am unable to create or edit fields if I have project config enabled in general.php

```
'*' => [
  'useProjectConfigFile' => true,
],
```

If I change that to false I can add fields, but as soon as I change it back to true, the fields disappear from the control panel.

Comment: Does this do anything? https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/project-config.html#production-changes-may-be-forgotten

Comment: I already looked at that before posting.